# All the threads are waiting on some barrier condition

Tags: java, multithreading, datasource, threadpool, connection-pooling

I have class like this.

```
class EmployeeTask implements Runnable {   
    public void run(){ 
        PayDAO  payDAO = new payDAO(session);
        String newSalary= payDAO.getSalary(empid);
        String newTitle= payDAO.getTitle(empid);

        EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO(session);
        List<Employee> employees = employeeDAO.getEmployees();
          employees.parallelStream().foreach(employee-> employeeDAO.add(newSalary, newTitle,employee));
    }
}
```

1. When I run the above code for one thread, it completes DB operation in 1 second and returns.
2. When I run it using parallelStream(), it will submit 8 requests, all 8 threads will wait for eight seconds and then return. Which means the server is executing the requests sequentially instead of parallel.

I checked the java jetty logs

Theread-1 Insert …

Theread-2 Insert …

…

Theread-8 Insert …

After eight seconds, that is 1 second per request

Theread-1 Insert … <= update 1

Theread-2 Insert … <= update 1

…

Theread-8 Insert … <= update 1

the same thing continues.

3. This clearly tells, all the  threads are getting blocked on one single resource, either the Datasource from my client java has only one connection so all the eight threads are getting blocked or the server is executing the requests one after the other.

I checked MaxPooledConnections — gives 20, MaxPooledConnections
PerNode - gives 5 default values.

I think the Vertica DB server is fine, maybe client is not having DatasourceConnection pooling, How do I enable Java side DatasourceConnection pooling. Any Code examples?

currently I am using mybatis ORM, with following datasource

```
<environments default=“XX”>
    <environment id=“XX”>
        <transactionManager type=“JDBC”/>
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:vertica://host:port/schema”/>
            <property name="username" value=“userName”/>
            <property name="password" value=“password”/>
           <property name="poolMaximumActiveConnections" value=“50”/>
            <property name="poolMaximumIdleConnections" value=“10”/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

What is the barrier condition all the threads are waiting on, my guess is Datasource connection. Any help is appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: can you take a thread dump during your test to see where threads are locked ?

Comment: All the threads were getting blocked on one single connection object. I solved this problem by opening, committing and closing the connections and session inside parallelstream.